# Sticky footer with Bootstrap and un-fixed height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I want to have a footer that stays on the bottom. The tricky part is that the footer consists of 3 images that are side by side that have a width of 100%... so the height is dynamic and changes with the width of the page.

How can I accomplish a sticky footer in this situation?

```
<div class="container-responsive">
<footer>
<div class="row no-gutter">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 no-padding">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/but-plan.png" alt="Plan" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 no-padding">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/but-administration.png" alt="Administration" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 no-padding">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/but-our-team.png" alt="Our Team" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
</footer>

</div> <!-- container -->

footer a {
  display:block;
}

footer img {
  width:100%; 
  height:auto; 
}
```

Comment: 100% width? and when are you on a 1920px screen as it looks? and on an iphone 5 with 320px?

Comment: it's responsive.... images stack on a smaller screen

Answer (score 1):

Use position fixed on your footer:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: that kinda works... the problem is that the content that is above the footer is being covered by the footer if the window is too small

Comment: Unless you mean something else by sticky, a fixed positioned element is the only way to accomplish what you're looking for. You'll have to add padding to the bottom of your container element to account for the space taken up by the footer. On smaller screens you might consider not fixing the footer or otherwise altering its contents to take up less room.

Answer (score 1):

Use fixed positioning and make your own:

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
  overflow-x:hidden /* don't do that */
}
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.xl {
  font-size:1500px;
}
footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:95px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto
}
footer>div {
  width:33.3333333333%;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
footer::after {
  content:"\0020";
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
  opacity:.3;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  position:absolute
}
footer>div:nth-child(2n) {
  transform:translateY(-20px);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="xl">
Content
</div>
<footer>
  <div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/850x700" >
  </div>
  <div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/850x700" >
  </div>
  <div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/850x700" >
  </div>
</footer>
</body>
```